# How i could print n number of parameters of any data type to a debug?

Tags: c++, winapi

I know of the `WINAPI` `OutputDebugString(L"");`

How I could go with a function able to receive `n` number of parameters which `any` data type, and print the value to a `debug`?

By debug I mean a window similar of the `Visual Studio` `Output`.

Comment: Don't be afraid to decompose this into parts.  You have a function that outputs a debug string, so perhaps what you need is a function that formats parameters of any data type **into a string**, then you would know how to output that string. So perhaps `std::to_string` will get you where you need to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a template:

```
   #include <utility>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <sstream>

    template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
    void Print(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
    
        ss<< std::forward<Arg>(arg);
        using expander = int[];
        (void)expander {
            0, (void(out << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
        };
    
        OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
    }
    
    
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    
        Print( 1, "abcde", 2, 3, "foo");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, what are the includes needed?

Comment: I edited the answer, add the includes.